# RDesktop wrong username or password when it's the right credentials

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote-control, credentials, rdesktop

I'm trying to connect to a Windows 7 system through rdesktop, and at the windows login I get wrong username and/or wrong password. I'm sure it's the right password.

It was working before.

I can login with another account through rdesktop.

What can be wrong here?

EDIT: I've tried to add the user to the remote desktop group.

Comment: is the machine connected to a domain?  How are you expressing your login credentials?

Comment: @Colyn1337 No, sorry I don't know what a domain is. It's not connected to anything, just has a hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the password and I was able to log on. Don't know what was wrong but maybe I find out one day :-)

Answer (score 4):

Couple of potential things...

Could be the domain name - if you are signing onto a machine local account (local on the machine you are RDPing to), try using the machine name and a backslash before the username (eg computername\username).  If a domain account, try using dokmain\username

Could be that the user is not authorised for remote logon.  Try adding the user to the remote desktop users group for that machine.

Ben

Answer (score 3):

If you had changed the Username. The folder under C:/Users does not get renamed.
So when connecting using Remote Desktop use the username which is present in C:/Users. It works. :)

Comment: Worked for me after all the usual suspects didn't.

Answer (score 2):

try this

- Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools and under Computer Management check  the user you created is the member of Remote Desktop Users and
- from my own experience , Change the password
- unheck the box "User must change password at next login" and check the box "password never expire"
- finally try comparing the two accounts if the above doesnot work .

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work try this: 1. create new user account (password and etc.) on a target computer, 2. add him to Administrator group (or Remote Desktop Users), I have tested it being him in Administrator group, 3. Connect through RDP with new user name and password.
It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open file explorer and user folder. Somehow, folder name are different from user name like HOME.  Use this folder name instead of Account name when use remote desktop.